# What are some good resources for learning photonics?

Tags: optics, photons, resource-recommendations, signal-processing

Including the generation, transmission, modulation, signal processing, amplification, and detection/sensing of light, I am interested in getting a good understanding of [photonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonics). Does anyone have any recommended resources to begin learning these things? I know math, statistics, and programming.

Comment: How much physics background do you have? If you haven't at least had a freshman "Physics for Scientists and Engineers" course, you probably want to start there.

Comment: I have taken basic physics classes, including high school AP and introductory college courses.

Answer (score 2):

**After reading some fundamental mathematics and physics or better to say becoming a sophomore you can start reading these books but absolutely some topics need more than fundamental mathematics and physics.**

- [Fundamentals of Photonics](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471358320.html) (Bahaa Saleh, Malvin Teich): This book provides an introduction to the fundamentals of photonics.
- [Fundamentals of Photonics](http://spie.org/x17229.xml) (Chandrasekhar Roychoudhuri): This book is designed for first- and second-year college students, but it is also suitable for both traditional and non-traditional students interested in learning the basics.
- [Elements of Photonics Vol. 1](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471839388.html) & [2](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471408158.html) (Keigo Iizuka): Elements of Photonics is comprised of two volumes. Even though cohesiveness between the two volumes is maintained, each volume can be used as a stand-alone textbook.
- [Photonics Vol. 1](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118225538.html), [2](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118225511.html) ,[3](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118225546.html) & [4](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118225538.html) (David L. Andrews): A complete and rather detailed discussion in photonics.
- [Photonics and Lasers](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471719749.html) (Richard S. Quimby):  An introduction to photonics and lasers that does not rely on complex mathematics.
- [Photonic Signal Processing](https://www.crcpress.com/Photonic-Signal-Processing-Techniques-and-Applications/Binh/9780849337628) (Le Nguyen Binh): This book was written to address the emerging techniques of processing and manipulating of signals propagating in an optical domain.
- [Photonics Rules of Thumb](http://spie.org/Publications/Book/540690) (Ed Friedman, John Lester Miller): This reference book is a handy compilation of 300 cost-saving, think-on-your-feet photonics rules of thumb designed to save hours of design time.
- [The Handbook of Photonics](https://www.crcpress.com/The-Handbook-of-Photonics-Second-Edition/Gupta-Ballato/9780849330957) (Mool C. Gupta, John Ballato): The book covers photonics materials, devices, and systems, respectively. An introductory chapter, new to this edition, provides an overview of photonics technology, innovation, and economic development.

Answer (score 0):

To start and have just an idea, I would suggest you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmEAes44j5s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsTl2qkWnp0